# Is it a good idea in a test class to use constants of the subject class in assertions?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, constants

Is it considered bad practice to use a constant of the subject class in assertions?

```
@Test
public void testSubjectMethod() throws Exception {
    Subject subject = new Subject()

    String result = subject.subjectMethod();

    Assert.assertEquals(result, Subject.VALUE);
}
```

Or should I maintain a separate value in the test class and use that?

```
private static final String SUBJECT_VALUE = "SUBJECT_VALUE";

@Test
public void testSubjectMethod() throws Exception {
    Subject subject = new Subject()

    String result = subject.subjectMethod();

    Assert.assertEquals(result, SUBJECT_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: other than duplication which obviously violates DRY and creating a minefield of subtle bugs what do you think you are accomplishing with duplicating data like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, use subject class constants in your tests**, for two reasons:

- Using a constant throughout your tests ensures that, if you change the value of the constant, you change it everywhere. If, instead, you duplicated the value in each test, you might only update one occurrence of the value and not another, and that might lead to the not-updated test passing when it shouldn't, and you would then have a bug. This consideration actually only requires that you use the same constant throughout your tests, not that it be the same constant in your tests and in subject classes, but if you have the constant in a subject class you might as well use it in tests too.
- The constant makes it clear that the value is important to the program and how it's used. Name constants in a way that makes their roles in the test, not just their roles in the implementation, clear. Using them in tests puts positive pressure on naming.

However,

- **Don't use constants from just any class in your tests**: The subject class might use a constant from another class, and you might need the value of that constant in tests of the subject class. However, if there is no other reason to refer to that other class in your test, don't do so just for the sake of the constant; that would unnecessarily couple test and implementation. If a class that you don't want to refer to has a meaningful constant that you don't want to duplicate, move it to a class that you don't mind referring to (perhaps the subject of the test) or to a new constant-only class and use it from there.
- **Don't use constants that provide a complex part of the subject class's behavior in your tests**. Doing so makes the test just a copy of the implementation, which reduces the power of the test. For example, it's probably a bad idea to use a regular expression constant used in the subject class in your test. Instead, write tests which show that the class does the right things with the right input, and that would still pass if you rewrote the class to not use the regular expression.

Comment: I don't understand "Don't use constants from implementation classes that wouldn't otherwise be referred to in the test". Can you please try to state it another way?

Comment: Revised. How's that?

Comment: The revision seems to imply, "Follow the Law of Demeter in your tests."

Comment: Can you expound on the type of bugs that would likely be caused by duplicating constants in tests?

Comment: Done. Regarding the LoD, that's pretty close, although the LoD is quite specifically about the relationship between two classes. The Dependency Inversion Principle is relevant: http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

Comment: You said "Using a constant throughout your tests ensures that, if you change the value of the constant, you change it everywhere. If, instead, you duplicated the value in each test, you might only update one occurrence of the value and not another, and that might lead to the not-updated test passing when it shouldn't, and you would then have a bug."

But then the values of the constants are not tested. Put another way, what if I would want the test to break if the constant was changed?

Comment: I don't normally want that. If I can make a test pass regardless of a constant's value by using the constant in the test, it suggests that the value is just incidental, not important to the program. What case are you thinking of where it would be useful to have the test require a specific value?